# Bash: Floating point calculations in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I am using the following script to read some numbers and calculate their average. However, it seems that floating point calculations cannot be performed like this.

```
hours=0
#echo "\n" >> user-list.txt
while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 || [[ -n $col1 ]]
do
    ((hours = hours + col5))
    #echo "$col1, $col2"
done < <(tail -n+2 user-list.txt)

((hours = hours/10))
echo "$hours" > wednesday.txt
```

How can I perform floating point calculations in this script?

Below is a sample of the input file:

```
Computer ID,User ID,M,T,W,T,F
Computer1,User3,5,7,3,5,2
Computer2,User5,8,8,8,8,8
Computer3,User4,0,8,0,8,4
Computer4,User1,5,4,5,5,8
```

TIA

Comment: Maybe use `awk` to process your data. It can do floating point calculation.

Comment: Use awk. You will need less code also.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show an example file `user-list.txt`. This will allow us to test a proposed solution.

Comment: @Bodo I have added a sample of the input file.

Comment: @SaadUrRehman : Use zsh. It can do floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` script will process the data and calculate the result.

```
awk -F, 'FNR>1 { hours += $5 } END { print hours/10; }' user-list.txt
```

Of course you can redirect the output to a file.

```
awk -F, 'FNR>1 { hours += $5 } END { print hours/10; }' user-list.txt > wednesday.txt
```

Explanation:

`-F,` specify `,` as field separator
`FNR>1` condition to skip first line of every file (the column names)
`{ hours += $5 }` sum up 5th column
`END { print hours/10; }` at the end print the result

The script allows to process more than one file like this:

```
awk -F, 'FNR>1 { hours += $5 } END { print hours/10; }' file1 file2 file3 [...] > outputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, 'NR > 1 { hours+=$5 } END { printf "%.2f",hours/10 }' <user-list.txt > wednesday.txt
```

Using awk, set comma as the field delimiter and then redirect user-list.txt into awk. For each line, set hours to hours plus the fifth comma separated value. At the end, divide hours by 10 and print to 2 decimal places. Redirect the output back out to wednesday.txt.